# Angular.js load, process and display dynamic template obtained via REST $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, templates, dynamic

I have an Angular app that needs to support customizable reporting.  My intention is to allow the user to select one of many reports available and have a back end REST api provide the template *and* the data as JSON (end user can customize the template).

The app would then insert the template somehow into a "reporting" view page then put the data in the scope and Angular should compile and display the report / template.

I've looked into ng-include however that seems to support only an URL or path to a document, however I have the template text already via the REST service and I cannot use static urls or file paths, this needs to be via REST api, if ng-include accepted the template text directly that might work but it doesn't.

I've tried writing a directive,  trying to call a method on the page (getTemplate()) that would load the template already fetched from the scope however my directive doesn't have access to the scope apparently.

What tactic should I use to accomplish this?  A directive seems best but I'm obviously doing it wrong and completely lost in the docs and my many attempts trying to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compile the dynamic template to an element on the DOM in a controller and then in the controller have something like this:

```
var el = angular.element('#myselector');   
el.html(mydynamichtmlfromresource);

$compile(el.contents())($scope);
```

I would setup your route with template with single DIV container (you could pull all the static container template in a single JavaScript file using HTMLToJS online tool or grunt task):

```
<section class="view">
  <div id="myselector"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried writing a directive, trying to call a method on the page
>   (getTemplate()) that would load the template already fetched from the
>   scope however my directive doesn't have access to the scope
>   apparently.

Yes you are right, but there is a way to pass data from scope to directive. lets say you want to pass a var "x" from scope to directive
use this

```
<directive directiveVar='x'/>
```

inside directive, you need to use isolated scope

```
 "scope": {
                    "directiveVar": "="
                },
```

this variable will be available only in controller and postlink function, so your directive template needs to be like this

```
<ng-bind-html="directiveVar"/>
```

inside the postlink you may need to use this code snippet

```
$scope.directiveVar =$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.directiveVar)
```

References

1. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml
2. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile

Comment: I'll try this, thank you, missed ngBindHtml before now.